# Library reference in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, dll, com

I've created custom library using Visual Studio. I want it to be referenced in Excel VBE, so it contains few COM Classes with specific GUIDs (classes that are not COM objects have their members hidden and cannot be used in Excel). VS created a bunch of files - .tlb, .dll.

Is it possible for Excel to call some function that is not inside any class, lets say I placed it in some module inside my library?

I've tried different access modifiers like "Public", "Friend". I've created Namespaces and Modules inside my library, but with no success.

Comment: When you use COM as a way to expose your API, only COM classes and COM methods are accessible from outside

Comment: Why would you not just access the COM Classes as COM Classes?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible for Excel to call arbitrary functions from arbitrary DLLs, including DLLs that are specifically COM libraries (DLLs which also implement the COM library interface)  And COM doesn't mind if the COM library also has other, non-COM, entry points.

> [Public | Private] Declare Function | Sub name Lib "libname" [Alias "aliasname"] [([arglist])] [As type]

Often Declarations are done with a DLL with the file type extension ".DLL", but that is not a requirement. "libname" is just the file name.

Comment: VBA cannot `Declare` a function that is not exported by a library, and libraries created by .NET do not export anything - unless DllExport is used, which is likely safe to assume from the question that it isn't.

Comment: @GSerg "Not in a class" and "some module in my library", I think it is safe to assume that the OP is not using DLLExport, but wants to do so.

Comment: I downloaded dllExport from GitHub, but I did not managed to make it work :( This is my first library and I am getting really frustrated. Is there any other way, to make it work? BTW Declare Ptr Safe Function do not work either...

Comment: dllExport is not something you download from GitHub. It is an attribute but not like 'public' or 'friend'. You need to ask a new question about how to do dll exports.